# CoffeeScript offering unexpected behavior with Excel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, coffeescript

Utilizing the following script with datatables on the site it seems as though every time a cell is copied from excel it is copied as a base64 image thereby executing the CoffeeScript that is shown in GitHub. How would I make it so that it ONLY executes on the imagecapture div when the div is selected? The best I can do right now is not execute unless it is on the same page but I need to narrow it down to the div element.

https://gist.github.com/STRd6/5286415

`<div id="imagecapture" class="span4 target contain" contenteditable="true" <?php if(!empty($ToolItems[0]->Base64)){ $Base64 = $ToolItems[0]->Base64; echo "style=\"background-image: url('$Base64')\";";}?>></div>`

Below I modified it a little to be selected with focus but when I paste it doesn't execute the post like it does when the focus wrapper isn't in it

````
$('#imagecapture').focus(function() {
(function($) {
    var defaults;
    $.event.fix = (function(originalFix) {
        return function(event) {
            event = originalFix.apply(this, arguments);
            if (event.type.indexOf("copy") === 0 || event.type.indexOf("paste") === 0) {
                event.clipboardData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
            }
            return event;
        };
    })($.event.fix);
    defaults = {
        callback: $.noop,
        matchType: /image.*/
    };
    return ($.fn.pasteImageReader = function(options) {
        if (typeof options === "function") {
            options = {
                callback: options
            };
        }
        options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this, element;
            element = this;
            $this = $(this);
            return $this.bind("paste", function(event) {
                var clipboardData, found;
                found = false;
                clipboardData = event.clipboardData;
                return Array.prototype.forEach.call(clipboardData.types, function(type, i) {
                    var file, reader;
                    if (found) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (
                        type.match(options.matchType) ||
                        clipboardData.items[i].type.match(options.matchType)
                    ) {
                        file = clipboardData.items[i].getAsFile();
                        reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function(evt) {
              var dataURL = evt.target.result;

                /** Add to Database */
                var queryString = window.location.search;
                var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
                var ToolID = urlParams.get('ToolID')
                console.log(dataURL);
                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: 'ajax/controller.php',
                  data: {
                    name: 'UpdateBaseImage',
                    UpdateBaseImage: 'True',
                    dataURL: dataURL,
                    ToolID: ToolID
                  },
                  success: function(data){
                    console.log('File Uploaded');
                  }
                });
              location.reload();
              

                            return options.callback.call(element, {
                                dataURL: evt.target.result,
                                event: evt,
                                file: file,
                                name: file.name
                            });
                        };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        return (found = true);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Removed the imagecapture focus on first and last line and instead checked for focus around the div and put the logic around the call to the controller so that it did not call this part of the function unless it was actively focused

```
          var FocusElement = document.getElementById('imagecapture');
          var isFocused = (document.activeElement === FocusElement);
          if (isFocused) {
            //CodeBlock
          }
```